# How to caption YouTube Livestreams?

Tags: http, post, youtube, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

YouTube is offering the possibility to send captions in a livestream as documented [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6077032?&ref_topic=2853697). However, this guide refers to a link from Youtube Studio Classic, which is no longer existent. In the new Live Control Room, I can only find a link for subtitles which looks like

```
http://upload.youtube.com/closedcaption?cid=....
```

and does not contain the parameters like `ns` or `sparams`.

How can I provide captions with the Live Control Room? There is also some misleading information on other pages - can I just use a simple HTTP POST or do I need to buy one of the [supported softwares](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3068031?hl=en)?

If it is not possible using POST, can I use the Livestreaming API for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me using below python code.

```
import time
import requests
from datetime  import datetime

word = "this is caption " + str(seq)

ytlink = "http://upload.youtube.com/closedcaption?cid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx="+str(seq)

post_fields = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + ' \n' + word + '\n' 

headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url=ytlink, data=post_fields.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
 
print(ytlink)
print(r.text)
```

Basically, others won't be required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It also works with c#. (Sorry, I think this is not the correct kind of code example, my first time trying to answer anything...)

```
string CAPTION_TEXT = "This text is displayed as caption.<br>"; // note, br used for linebreak in caption
string STREAM_ID = "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeee";
int sequence = 1;
string url = "http://upload.youtube.com/closedcaption?cid="+STREAM_ID+"&seq="+sequence; // increment sequence every time you send
string message = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" +
            dateTime.ToString("HH") + ":" +
            dateTime.ToString("mm") + ":" +
            dateTime.ToString("ss.fff")+
            " region:reg1#cue1\n"+
            CAPTION_TEXT+"\n"
var content = new StringContent(message);
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
if(statusCode == "200") SUCCESS();
```